# ¿Como repetir la acción de un formulario para que inserte varios registros en una base de datos mysql y sea parecido a un punto de venta?

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Hola a todos actualmente estoy desarrollando un formulario sobre pedidos, el cual funciona e inserta los datos en una base de datos, el problema es que un mismo pedido puede tener varios productos y por cada producto una unidad distinta, cantidad, fecha de embarque, notas y etiquetado, lo único que se escribiría una sola vez seria el cliente y la orden de compra ya que es parte del mismo pedido. Pienso en un sistema donde existe un formulario se le da agregar y aparece en una lista el producto agregado, algo parecido a un punto de venta.Agradecería mucho el apoyo de esta comunidad,

```
?>




<body>
    <a href="index.php">Inicio</a>


    <form action="add.php" method="post" name="form1">
                <div class="table-responsive" >

        <table class="table-bordered table-striped">




            <tr> 
                <td>Cliente</td>
               <td> <select name="cliente">
 <?php

                    $sql = "Select cliente from clientes";

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['cliente'].'</option>';
       }
     ?>
 </select> </td>

            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <td>Orden de compra</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="orden_de_compra"  required="required"  placeholder="orden de compra" maxlength="19"></td>
            </tr>



                <tr> 
                <td>Producto</td>
               <td> <select name="producto">
 <?php

                    $sql = "Select producto from productos";

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['producto'].'</option>';
       }
     ?>
 </select> </td>

            </tr>

                <tr> 
                <td>Unidad</td>
               <td> <select name="unidad">
 <?php

                    $sql = "Select unidad from unidades";

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['unidad'].'</option>';
       }
     ?>
 </select> </td>

            </tr>


                <tr> 
                <td>Cantidad</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="cantidad" required="required"  placeholder="cantidad" maxlength="10"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr> 
                <td>Fecha de embarque</td>
            <td> <input type="date" name="fecha_de_embarque" required="required"  placeholder="fecha de embarque"/> </td>

            </tr>


                <tr> 
                <td>Notas</td>
  <td> <textarea  rows="2" cols="30" name='notas' id='notas' maxlength="255"></textarea> </td>

            </tr>


                    <tr> 
                <td>Etiquetado</td>
            <td>   <input type="radio" name="etiquetado" value="Si" checked> Etiquetado 
     <input type="radio" name="etiquetado" value="No"> No etiquetado    </td>
            </tr>   





            <tr> 
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Registrar pedido"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Les dejo captura de mi sistema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pudiste solucionar tu duda?, estoy buscando la misma información pero para cargar datos de educación de personas, soy nuevo en esto. Saludos.

Comment: Utiliza ciclos for

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar javascript o mas fácil jquery para que se inserte todo lo que el cliente quiera para después poder guardarlo en la base de datos.
aquí te mando una pequeña idea, espero te sirva de algo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <select id="product">
  <option value="producto1">producto1</option>
  <option value="producto2">producto2</option>
  <option value="producto3">producto3</option>
 </select><br>

 <a href="#" onclick="Add();">Agregar producto</a>

<form>
 <table id="campos"></table>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

var cont = 0;

function Add(){
 var valor= $("#product").val();
 cont++;
 producto='<tr>';
 producto += '<td id="rut'+cont+'">Producto:<input disabled="true" 
 style="border: 1px solid white;" type="text" value="'+ valor+'" size="20" 
 id="campo' + cont + '"&nbsp; name="campo' + cont + '"&nbsp; /></td>';
 producto+='</tr>';

 $("#campos").append(producto);
 }

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo realmente que es lo que hace tu codigo amigo, para simpificar todo me interesa que el usuario pueda agregar productos como si fuera un carrito de compras. eliminar y que cuando le de enviar se agreguen estos multiples registros en la base de datos, de preferencia que funcione con PDO.